# Is it possible to get the original matrix from nested FOR loops that iterate over a matrices rows and columns?

Tags: r

I'm learning how to iterate over rows and columns, and I was sort of expecting a regular looking matrix as the output, but instead get (what I believe are) a series of vectors of length 1 listing all of the values.

Is it possible to output a matrix from a nested FOR loop like this; or do FOR loops always output vectors of length 1?

```
m1 <- matrix(1:12,3,4)

for (i in seq_len(nrow(m1))) {
  for (j in seq_len(ncol(m1))) {
    print(m1[i,j])
  }
}
```

Comment: In the inner loop, `i` is a single value and so is `j`, so `m1[i, j]` gives you the single cell in the `i`th row and `j`th column. What were you hoping this code would achieve?

Comment: Ah you're right, that's so odd.

I thought I'd get something like:

m1 <- matrix(1:12,3,4)
m1[1:3, 1:4]

Where I get all the values.

I need to figure out how to change that so i and j aren't single values. Are you aware of how to do that?

I wanted i to be 1:3 and j to be 1:4

Comment: That would just be something like `m1[seq_len(nrow(m1)), seq_len(ncol(m1))]`, no for loops needed.

Comment: Just curious to see if FOR loops could do it for future reference, that's all. Got it from another user though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `cat` instead of `print`

```
m1 <- matrix(1:12,3,4)
for (i in seq_len(nrow(m1))) {
    for (j in seq_len(ncol(m1))) {
        cat(m1[i,j])
    }
    cat("\n")
}
```